# TableAdapter.Update(DataSet) makes cyrillic letters appear as question marks in dgv

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tableadapter, cyrillic

I have an application that consists of a DataGridView and a few buttons to manage it more easily (it is about managing gym subscriptions). I add the row to the DataGridView like this.

```
DataTable dataTable = ((SubscriptionsDatabaseDataSet)(tableBindingSource.DataSource)).Tables[0];
dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {id, name, dateMade, expiryDate, daysRemaining, sessionsRemaining, cardType});
```

and after that, in order to save the data to the database I do this:

```
this.tableTableAdapter.Update(this.subscriptionsDatabaseDataSet);
this.tableTableAdapter.Update(this.subscriptionsDatabaseDataSet.Table);
```

The card type is in *cyrillic* and it appears fine if I do not call `tableTableAdapter.Update()`, it only gets broken and appears as question marks after I call the method.

Comment: What's the data type of the column in database?

Comment: VARCHAR (MAX). I have also tried text but it was still the same.

Comment: Change the type to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: What's the data type of the column in database?
>   A: VARCHAR (MAX).

You should change the type of the column to [`NVARCHAR(MAX)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) to support variable length unicode data.